# Tableview Multi-Sections Number of Rows Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableview

I have the following four list of products:

```
var products1 = [Product]()
var products2 = [Product]()
var products3 = [Product]()
var products4 = [Product]()
```

I'd like to have a tableView with multi sections including headers. I have no problem adding headers with no error; but when it gets to numberofrows then it gives me an error.

this is my `numberOfSections`:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    var numberOfSections:Int = 1

    if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Order_Received {
        numberOfSections = 1
    }else
        if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Picking {
            numberOfSections = 2
        } else
            if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.ReadyForDelivery || orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.OnTheWay || orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Delivered {
                numberOfSections = 4
    }

    return numberOfSections
}
```

Basically based on the status of an order; I want to have different number of sections (1 section, 2 sections or 4 sections). But I keep getting the error that it is out of range. This is how I have coded my number of Rows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var numberOfRows = 0

        if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Order_Received {
            numberOfRows = products1.count
        }else

            if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Picking {

                if section == 0 {
                    numberOfRows = products1.count
                } else
                    if section == 1 {
                        numberOfRows = products2.count
                }

            } else
                if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.ReadyForDelivery || orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.OnTheWay || orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Delivered {
                    if section == 0 {
                        numberOfRows = products1.count
                    } else
                        if section == 1 {
                            numberOfRows = products2.count
                        } else
                            if section == 2 {
                                numberOfRows = products3.count
                            } else
                                if section == 3 {
                                    numberOfRows = products4.count
                    }
        }
return numberOfRows
}
```

This is my `cellForRoaAt` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.MyOrderCartCell, for: indexPath) as?  MyOrderCartCell {

            if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Order_Received {

                if indexPath.section == 0 {
                    cell.configureCell(order: orderDetails, product: products1[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
                }

            } else
                if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Picking {

                    if indexPath.section == 0 {
                        cell.configureCell(order: orderDetails, product: products1[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
                    } else
                        if indexPath.section == 1 {
                            cell.configureCell(order: orderDetails, product: products2[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
                    }

                } else
                    if orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.ReadyForDelivery || orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.OnTheWay || orderDetails.status == DatabaseRef.Delivered {

                        if indexPath.section == 0 {
                            cell.configureCell(order: orderDetails, product: products1[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
                        } else
                            if indexPath.section == 1 {
                                cell.configureCell(order: orderDetails, product: products2[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
                            } else
                                if indexPath.section == 2 {
                                    cell.configureCell(order: orderDetails, product: products3[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
                                } else
                                    if indexPath.section == 3 {
                                        cell.configureCell(order: orderDetails, product: products4[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
                        }
            }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Error Message is:

`Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

Comment: why aren't you use one Product array with status field? It is make easy your approach.

Comment: The quantity of products in one order is too many so its not feasible to set an approved status for each product in the Product array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is nothing wrong with my code above. I had a problem somewhere else with updating/adding products to my tableview where I was not adding to the correct section. It was adding only to section 0. So above code is correct.